# Move records from a table in Azure MySql Database to Azure PostgreSql Db

Tags: mysql, postgresql, azure

I am new to Azure. I have a requirement to transfer data from a table in a transaction MySqlDb which is stored in json blobs(I am not aware why they have used a nosql format writes in a sql db) to a table in PostgreSql but in a flattened format. What is the best way to achieve this? This is not a one time task, but needs to be done everytime there is a ingestion to the transaction db and I need to push those records into postgresql db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an ETL (Extract - Transform - Load) tool. The one available on Azure is the Azure Data Factory, which has connectors for MySQL, PostGreSQL and many more. So basically you'll create a pipeline, use the copy data activity to extract the data from MYSQL and then insert it into PostGreSQL

You can get more information in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mysql

Comment: Thiago, thank you for your reply. So would that mean i need to copy date from MySql db to Azure Data Factory and then copy from Azure Data Factory to Postgresql db??

Comment: not, I'll edit my answer so you can understand better

Comment: Hi @Thiago Custodio, I was able to ETL the json colmuns using the basic Copy Activity with the Query Method.. Can you please suggest a more efficient way to ETL such data?                                                                                                                           My Data is of the following type :"forecast": [{"time": "2019-11-20T00:00:00.000+0000", "quantity": 246}, {"time": "2019-11-21T00:00:00.000+0000", "quantity": 222}, {"time": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000+0000", "quantity": 202}, {"time": "2019-11-